# Unable to send emails, handshake times out

Tags: email, ssl, smtp

EE 6.2.7

I'm trying to connect to office365 exchange server using SMTP via STARTTLS.

When `stream_socket_enable_crypto()` attempts to establish a secure connection, it says `SSL: Handshake timed out`.

I ran this in the cPanel terminal: `openssl s_client -connect smtp.office365.com:587`

And got this result:

[image]

Any ideas why it fails to connect?

I should add that this problem sprang up without any changes made to email settings or any version updates (I've updated versions since the problem started in the hopes that the update would help, but the same problem persists). It happens with contact forms, password reset requests, checkout notifications, etc.

Comment: I'm sure there's a few people out here with a lot more experience on this front.  But it might be worth checking out this article on ExpressionEngine University

https://u.expressionengine.com/article/using-microsoft-office-365-for-smtp-email

Comment: Thanks for the link. I already had all the settings set as the document suggests, except I realized the newline setting wasn't sticking, so I had to go in and hard-code it. Other than that, it was helpful to be reminded of the Send Email Utility in the admin panel, which gave me a much more concise and direct testing environment. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving this by identifying where it was failing in the core Email class, and why. I ended up hard coding the newline variable to "\n\r", and updating the `stream_socket_enable_crypto()` method from `STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT` type to `STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT`. I really don't like digging into the core files and changing things, but I didn't really have any other option, as emails needed to be working on the website.

I wonder if this is something that's been occurring with anyone else, or if it's just me.